# HTTP google maps Polyline

Tags: json, angular, google-maps

I have a Ionic App using google maps . I am trying to get latitude and longitude from data json api for flight route then inject that data arrays to Google Maps polyline . Fetch data json api working fine without problem , but when l put objects inside Google Maps l get error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getPosition' in 40.11882
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getPosition' in 40.11882
    at getLatLng (Common.js:544)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.convertToPositionArray (Common.js:575)
    at Map.addPolyline (Map.js:1231)
    at vendor.js:76340
```

my code

```
export class HomePage{
  map: GoogleMap;
  latitude: any;
  longitude: any;
  dates=[]
  constructor(
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private http: HTTP
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Since ngOnInit() is executed before `deviceready` event,
    // you have to wait the event.
    this.platform.ready();
    this.getmarker();
     this.loadMap();


  }

  async getmarker(){
       this.http.get('/v1/flightjson?flightId=201',{},{})

    .then( data=>{

      // this.latitude = JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight.track.latitude
      // this.longitude = JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight.track

      for(let datas of JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight['track']) {
        this.longitude = datas.longitude
        this.latitude  = datas.latitude

        console.log(this.longitude, this.latitude)
      }




    })

  }

  loadMap() {


    let AIR_PORTS = [

      this.longitude = datas.longitude
        this.latitude  = datas.latitude

    ];
    console.log(AIR_PORTS)


    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');

    let polyline: Polyline = this.map.addPolylineSync({
      points: AIR_PORTS,
      color: '#AA00FF',
      width: 10,
      geodesic: true,
      clickable: true  // clickable = false in default
    });

    polyline.on(GoogleMapsEvent.POLYLINE_CLICK).subscribe((params: any) => {
      let position: LatLng = <LatLng>params[0];

      let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        position: position,
        title: position.toUrlValue(),
        disableAutoPan: true
      });
      marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
  }
}
```

console log  for `AIR_PORTS`

[image]

[my data json url](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4adce21191d047f4a008d31db1d5ee22)

[original code](https://github.com/mapsplugin/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/blob/master/src/app/polyline/polyline.page.ts)

```
export class PolylinePage implements OnInit {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(private platform: Platform) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    // Since ngOnInit() is executed before `deviceready` event,
    // you have to wait the event.
    await this.platform.ready();
    await this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    let HND_AIR_PORT = {lat: 35.548852, lng: 139.784086};
    let SFO_AIR_PORT = {lat: 37.615223, lng: -122.389979};
    let HNL_AIR_PORT = {lat: 21.324513, lng: -157.925074};
    let AIR_PORTS = [
      HND_AIR_PORT,
      HNL_AIR_PORT,
      SFO_AIR_PORT
    ];

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
      camera: {
        target: AIR_PORTS
      }
    });

    let polyline: Polyline = this.map.addPolylineSync({
      points: AIR_PORTS,
      color: '#AA00FF',
      width: 10,
      geodesic: true,
      clickable: true  // clickable = false in default
    });

    polyline.on(GoogleMapsEvent.POLYLINE_CLICK).subscribe((params: any) => {
      let position: LatLng = <LatLng>params[0];

      let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        position: position,
        title: position.toUrlValue(),
        disableAutoPan: true
      });
      marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: would you be able to add a online example for this?

Comment: check this link , [https://mapsplugin.github.io/ionic-googlemaps-quickdemo-v4/polyline] , my project is same this . but l want use lat and long from data json api

Comment: yes i understand, it must be something you are doing wrong so if you can create a stackblitz demo on what you have done so far, we could take a look and find it

Comment: l updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the way you are reading data and passing data to the GoogleMap is incorrect, Please try the following

```
export class HomePage{
  map: GoogleMap;
  points: {lng: number, lat: number}[] = [];

  constructor(
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private platform: Platform,
    private http: HTTP
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.platform.ready();
    this.getmarker();
    this.loadMap();
  }

  async getmarker(){
       this.http.get('/v1/flightjson?flightId=201',{},{})

    .then( data=>{

      for(let datas of JSON.parse(data.data).result.response.data.flight['track']) {
        this.points.push({lng: datas.longitude, lat: datas.latitude});
      }
    })
  }

  loadMap() {


    let AIR_PORTS = this.points;
    console.log(AIR_PORTS)


    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');

    let polyline: Polyline = this.map.addPolylineSync({
      points: AIR_PORTS,
      color: '#AA00FF',
      width: 10,
      geodesic: true,
      clickable: true  // clickable = false in default
    });

    polyline.on(GoogleMapsEvent.POLYLINE_CLICK).subscribe((params: any) => {
      let position: LatLng = <LatLng>params[0];

      let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
        position: position,
        title: position.toUrlValue(),
        disableAutoPan: true
      });
      marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
  }
}
```

you can find a working example here which i tried with your data - [Example Demo](https://angular-ebtppj.stackblitz.io/).
And code from here [Example Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebtppj)

Comment: what do you mean? when you run the app locally?

Comment: when l run app on really device l get fatal error ` app has stopped working`

Comment: really device? please share a working demo. just check the link i have provide i have shown how to read the data there.

Comment: l readed , and l copied your answer  . but when l run app l get message  app has stopped working

Comment: finally . is work now , `this.loadMap()` it was running before `this.getmarker()` .

Comment: Do you have idea how to add icon to map ? example if l want to add aircraft to the end of line of polyline ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191468/discussion-between-imanshu15-and-ali-ghassan).